# Dealing with responsive css when phone is flipped horizontally

Tags: html, css

Hi I'm currently creating a website for someone and my boss noticed that when the phone is flipped horizontally for example on a Iphone X, my images that are responsive the text in the middle is shifted up and you cannot read it. It's hard to explain in words so I have 2 pictures, one with what I'm getting and one with what I'm kind of looking for, I've been on this for a little while now.

What I'm getting:

[image]

What I'm looking for:

[image]

This is my code:

HTML

```
<?php include ('header.php') ?>

<div class="hero-container">
    <span>Active Printing</span>
    <span style="margin-top: 150px; border: none; font-size: 20px; letter-spacing: 0em;"><a class="hero-btn" href="#services">Services</a></span>
</div>
<a href="#">
<div id="services" class="slide-container">
    <div class="slider">
        
        <div class="slide business1">
            <div class="caption">
                <h2>Business Printing</h2>
                <p>We service all your printing needs. Business cards, flyers, invoices and much more.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide business2">
            <div class="caption">
                <h2>Slide2</h2>
                <p>Test</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide business3">
            <div class="caption">
                <h2>Slide3</h2>
                <p>Test</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide business4">
            <div class="caption">
                <h2>Slide4</h2>
                <p>Test</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</a>

<div style="width: 100%; height: 5rem;">
</div>
<!-- <a href="#"><button class="slide-btn"><i class="fas fa-sort-up" style="margin-right: 5px;"></i>Business Printing<i style="margin-left: 5px;" class="fas fa-sort-up"></i></button></a> -->

<a href="#">
<div id="services" class="slide-container">
    <div class="slider">
        <div class="slide canvas1">
            <div class="caption">
                <h2>Canvas Printing</h2>
                <p>Canvas prints are a unique way to personalize any space and make great gifts.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide canvas2">
            <div class="caption">
                <h2>Slide2</h2>
                <p>Test</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide canvas3">
            <div class="caption">
                <h2>Slide3</h2>
                <p>Test</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide canvas4">
            <div class="caption">
                <h2>Slide4</h2>
                <p>Test</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</a>

<div style="width: 100%; height: 5rem;">
</div>
<!-- <a href="#"><button class="slide-btn"><i class="fas fa-sort-up" style="margin-right: 5px;"></i>Canvas Printing<i style="margin-left: 5px;" class="fas fa-sort-up"></i></button></a> -->

<a href="#">
<div id="services" class="slide-container">
    <div class="slider">
        <div class="slide embroidery1">
            <div class="caption">
                <h2>Embroidery</h2>
                <p>Embroidery is the craft of decorating fabric or other materials using a needle to apply thread or yarn. Embroidery may also incorporate other materials such as pearls, beads, quills, and sequins.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide embroidery2">
            <div class="caption">
                <h2>Slide2</h2>
                <p>Test</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide embroidery3">
            <div class="caption">
                <h2>Slide3</h2>
                <p>Test</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide embroidery4">
            <div class="caption">
                <h2>Slide4</h2>
                <p>Test</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</a>

<div style="width: 100%; height: 5rem;">
</div>

<!-- <a href="#"><button class="slide-btn"><i class="fas fa-sort-up" style="margin-right: 5px;"></i>Embroidery<i style="margin-left: 5px;" class="fas fa-sort-up"></i></button></a> -->


<?php include('footer.php') ?>
```

CSS

```
*, *::before, *::after {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

html {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 999;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 117rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 1.5rem;
}

.menu-icons{
    color: #eee;
    font-size: 4rem;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 2rem;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 1500;
    display: none;
}

nav {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 8rem;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(225,225,225, 0.1);
}

.logo {
    display: flex;
    margin-right: 5rem;
}

.nav-list {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
}

.nav-list li {
    line-height: 8rem;
    position: relative;
}

.sub-menu li {
    line-height: 4rem;
}

.nav-list a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    background-color: #1E90FF;
    padding: 0 1.5rem;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transition: color 650ms;
    transition: background-color 650ms;
}

.nav-list a:hover {
    color: black;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.cart {
    height: 30px;
    width: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.btn {
    padding: 1.3rem;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #1E90FF;
    border: 2px solid #1E90FF;
    border-radius: 5rem;
    transition: background-color 650ms;
}

.btn:hover {
    color: black;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.sub-menu {
    width: 20rem;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    border-top: 3px solid #00BFFF;
    z-index: 100;
    top: 16rem;
    transition: all 650ms ease;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.sub-menu::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -2.5rem;
    left: 3rem;
    border: 1.2rem solid transparent;
    border-bottom-color: #00BFFF;
}

.sub-menu .sub-menu::before {
    top: .9rem;
    left: -2.5rem;
    border: 1.2rem solid transparent;
    border-right-color: #00BFFF;
}

.sub-menu .sub-menu{
    border-top: none;
    border-left: 3px solid #00BFFF;
    top: 0;
    left: 160%;
}

.nav-list li:hover > .sub-menu {
    top: 8rem;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}

.sub-menu li:hover > .sub-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
}
    
li.move-right {
    margin: auto 0 auto auto;
    line-height: initial;
    transition: color 650ms;
    transition: background-color 650ms;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1050px) {
    .nav-list {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        height: 100vh;
        display:none;
        align-items: initial;
        flex-direction: column;
        background-color: #1E90FF;
        z-index: 1000;
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }
    
    .nav-list li {
        line-height: 6rem;
    }
    
    .sub-menu {
        position: initial;
        border: 3px solid transparent;
        border-left-color: #00BFFF;
        margin-left: 1rem;
        max-height: 0;
    }
    
    .sub-menu::before {
        display: none;
    }
    
    .nav-list li:hover > .sub-menu{
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
        max-height: initial;
    }
    
    li.move-right {
        margin: 0 auto 0 0;
        line-height: initial;
    }
    
    .menu-icons {
        display: block;
    }
    
    .fas fa-times {
        display: none;
    }
    
    nav.active .fas fa-times{
        display: block;
    }
    
    nav.active .fas fa-bars{
        display: none;
    }
    
    nav.active .nav-list {
        display:flex;
    }
}

.hero-container {
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: linear-gradient(
    rgba(0,0,0,0.5),
    rgba(0,0,0,0.5)),
    url(../images/heroImage.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    
}

.hero-container span {
    color: white;
    font-size: 50px;
    letter-spacing: 0.2em;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border: 10px solid white;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 3px 14px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.hero-container a {
    padding: 15px 16px;
    color: white;
    background-color: #1E90FF;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 5rem;
    transition: background-color 650ms;
}

.hero-btn:hover {
    color: black;
    background-color: yellow;
    transition: background-color 650ms;
}

.slide-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 25vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 5px solid #1E90FF;
    box-shadow: 0 16px 32px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 10px 30px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.slide-container .slider {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 500%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
     /* animation: animate 30s linear infinite; */
    
}
    
.slide-container .slider .slide {
    position: relative;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    float : left;
}
    
.slide-container .slider .slide .caption{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 60px;
    left: 60px;
    right: 60px;
    padding: 30px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide .caption h2 {
    margin: 0 0 20px;
    padding: 0;
    color: white;
    font-size: 48px;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide .caption p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
}



.slide-container .slider .slide.business1 {
    background: url(../images/business1.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.business2 {
    background: url(../images/business2.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.business3 {
    background: url(../images/business3.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.business4 {
    background: url(../images/business4.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.canvas1 {
    background: url(../images/canvas1.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.canvas2 {
    background: url(../images/canvas2.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.canvas3 {
    background: url(../images/canvas3.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.canvas4 {
    background: url(../images/canvas4.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.embroidery1 {
    background: url(../images/embroidery1.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.embroidery2 {
    background: url(../images/embroidery2.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.embroidery3 {
    background: url(../images/embroidery3.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.embroidery4 {
    background: url(../images/embroidery4.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}



@keyframes animate {
    0% 
    {
        left: 0;
    }
    
    20% 
    {
        left: 0;
    }
    
    25% 
    {
        left: -100%;
    }
    
    45% 
    {
        left: -100%;
    }
    50% 
    {
        left: -200%;
    }
    70% 
    {
        left: -200%;
    }
    75% 
    {
        left: -300%;
    }
    95% 
    {
        left: -300%;
    }
    100% {
        left: -400%;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .slide-container .slider .slide .caption{
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide .caption h2 {
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide .caption p {
    font-size: 16px;
}

}

.slide-btn {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 5rem;
    border: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    background-color: white;
    transition: background-color 650ms;
}

.slide-btn:hover {
    background-color: #1E90FF;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: background-color 650ms;
}

.footer-row {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.footer {
    background-color: #1E90FF;
    padding: 70px 0;
    
}

.footer-container {
    max-width: 1170px;
    margin: auto;
}

li {
    list-style: none;
}

.footer-col {
    width: 25%;
    padding: 0 15px;
}

.footer-col h4 {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: white;
    text-transform: capatalize;
    margin-bottom: 35px;
    font-weight: 500;
    position: relative;
}

.footer-col h4::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -10px;
    background-color: white;
    height: 2px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 50px;
}

.footer-col ul li:not(:last-child) {
    margin-bottom: 10px;

}

.footer-col ul li a {
    font-size: 16px;
    text-transform: capatalize;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.footer-col ul li a:hover {
    color: yellow;
    padding-left: 8px;
}

.footer-col .social-links {
    display: inline-block;
     /* height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);*/
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: white;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.footer-col .social-links:hover {
    color: yellow;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .footer-col 
    {
        width: 50%;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
    }
    
}

@media (max-width: 574px) {
    .footer-col 
    {
        width: 100%;
    }
    
}
```

These are the properties that are dealing with the styling of the stuff I'm looking for to be changed

```
.slide-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 25vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 5px solid #1E90FF;
    box-shadow: 0 16px 32px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 10px 30px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.slide-container .slider {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 500%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
     /* animation: animate 30s linear infinite; */
    
}
    
.slide-container .slider .slide {
    position: relative;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    float : left;
}
    
.slide-container .slider .slide .caption{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 60px;
    left: 60px;
    right: 60px;
    padding: 30px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide .caption h2 {
    margin: 0 0 20px;
    padding: 0;
    color: white;
    font-size: 48px;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide .caption p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
}



.slide-container .slider .slide.business1 {
    background: url(../images/business1.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.business2 {
    background: url(../images/business2.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.business3 {
    background: url(../images/business3.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.business4 {
    background: url(../images/business4.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.canvas1 {
    background: url(../images/canvas1.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.canvas2 {
    background: url(../images/canvas2.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.canvas3 {
    background: url(../images/canvas3.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.canvas4 {
    background: url(../images/canvas4.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.embroidery1 {
    background: url(../images/embroidery1.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.embroidery2 {
    background: url(../images/embroidery2.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.embroidery3 {
    background: url(../images/embroidery3.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.embroidery4 {
    background: url(../images/embroidery4.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think most of what you want done can be outside of an `@media` queries. If you place them outside you can still make them responsive to screen size. Then as far as the height goes you'll want to add a `@media` query for `max-height`. In the snippet below I used 400px.

For the most part the only need for the media queries is to change the `font-size` IOT be sure it still fits as the boxes resize. Additionally in the height query the padding is reduced to 2px (could even be 0) to prevent the text from being pushed outside of the box.

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

html {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 999;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 117rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 1.5rem;
}

.menu-icons {
  color: #eee;
  font-size: 4rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 2rem;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1500;
  display: none;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 8rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(225, 225, 225, 0.1);
}

.logo {
  display: flex;
  margin-right: 5rem;
}

.nav-list {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav-list li {
  line-height: 8rem;
  position: relative;
}

.sub-menu li {
  line-height: 4rem;
}

.nav-list a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  background-color: #1e90ff;
  padding: 0 1.5rem;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: color 650ms;
  transition: background-color 650ms;
}

.nav-list a:hover {
  color: black;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.cart {
  height: 30px;
  width: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.btn {
  padding: 1.3rem;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #1e90ff;
  border: 2px solid #1e90ff;
  border-radius: 5rem;
  transition: background-color 650ms;
}

.btn:hover {
  color: black;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.sub-menu {
  width: 20rem;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border-top: 3px solid #00bfff;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 16rem;
  transition: all 650ms ease;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.sub-menu::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -2.5rem;
  left: 3rem;
  border: 1.2rem solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: #00bfff;
}

.sub-menu .sub-menu::before {
  top: 0.9rem;
  left: -2.5rem;
  border: 1.2rem solid transparent;
  border-right-color: #00bfff;
}

.sub-menu .sub-menu {
  border-top: none;
  border-left: 3px solid #00bfff;
  top: 0;
  left: 160%;
}

.nav-list li:hover > .sub-menu {
  top: 8rem;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.sub-menu li:hover > .sub-menu {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
}

li.move-right {
  margin: auto 0 auto auto;
  line-height: initial;
  transition: color 650ms;
  transition: background-color 650ms;
}

.slide-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 5px solid #1e90ff;
  box-shadow: 0 16px 32px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
    0 10px 30px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.slide-container .slider {
  width: 500%;
  height: 100%;
  /* animation: animate 30s linear infinite; */
}

.slide-container .slider .slide {
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide .caption {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 97%;
  height: 90%;
  padding: 10px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.slide-container .slider .slide .caption h2 {
  padding: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 4em;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide .caption p {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1050px) {
  .nav-list {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    display: none;
    align-items: initial;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: #1e90ff;
    z-index: 1000;
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }

  .nav-list li {
    line-height: 6rem;
  }

  .sub-menu {
    position: initial;
    border: 3px solid transparent;
    border-left-color: #00bfff;
    margin-left: 1rem;
    max-height: 0;
  }

  .sub-menu::before {
    display: none;
  }

  .nav-list li:hover > .sub-menu {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    max-height: initial;
  }

  li.move-right {
    margin: 0 auto 0 0;
    line-height: initial;
  }

  .menu-icons {
    display: block;
  }

  .fas fa-times {
    display: none;
  }

  nav.active .fas fa-times {
    display: block;
  }

  nav.active .fas fa-bars {
    display: none;
  }

  nav.active .nav-list {
    display: flex;
  }
}

.hero-container {
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)),
    url(../images/heroImage.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.hero-container span {
  color: white;
  font-size: 50px;
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: 10px solid white;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px 14px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.hero-container a {
  padding: 15px 16px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #1e90ff;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 5rem;
  transition: background-color 650ms;
}

.hero-btn:hover {
  color: black;
  background-color: yellow;
  transition: background-color 650ms;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.business1 {
  background: url(https://thumbor.forbes.com/thumbor/960x0/https%3A%2F%2Fblogs-images.forbes.com%2Falejandrocremades%2Ffiles%2F2018%2F07%2Fdesk-3139127_1920-1200x773.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.business2 {
  background: url(../images/business2.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.business3 {
  background: url(../images/business3.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.business4 {
  background: url(../images/business4.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.canvas1 {
  background: url(https://www.costcophotocenter.com/dynamic/en-US/Shop/canvas/badgeright_canvas);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.canvas2 {
  background: url(../images/canvas2.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.canvas3 {
  background: url(../images/canvas3.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.canvas4 {
  background: url(../images/canvas4.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.embroidery1 {
  background: url(https://www.boomerempowerment.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/images2832-5d14ce0fca563.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.embroidery2 {
  background: url(../images/embroidery2.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.embroidery3 {
  background: url(../images/embroidery3.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.embroidery4 {
  background: url(../images/embroidery4.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    left: 0;
  }

  20% {
    left: 0;
  }

  25% {
    left: -100%;
  }

  45% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  50% {
    left: -200%;
  }
  70% {
    left: -200%;
  }
  75% {
    left: -300%;
  }
  95% {
    left: -300%;
  }
  100% {
    left: -400%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
}

.slide-btn {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5rem;
  border: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  background-color: white;
  transition: background-color 650ms;
}

.slide-btn:hover {
  background-color: #1e90ff;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color 650ms;
}

.footer-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.footer {
  background-color: #1e90ff;
  padding: 70px 0;
}

.footer-container {
  max-width: 1170px;
  margin: auto;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

.footer-col {
  width: 25%;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.footer-col h4 {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
  text-transform: capatalize;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
  font-weight: 500;
  position: relative;
}

.footer-col h4::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -10px;
  background-color: white;
  height: 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 50px;
}

.footer-col ul li:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.footer-col ul li a {
  font-size: 16px;
  text-transform: capatalize;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.footer-col ul li a:hover {
  color: yellow;
  padding-left: 8px;
}

.footer-col .social-links {
  display: inline-block;
  /* height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);*/
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: white;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.footer-col .social-links:hover {
  color: yellow;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .footer-col {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 574px) {
  .footer-col {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .slide-container .slider .slide .caption h2 {
    font-size: 3em;
  }
  .slide-container .slider .slide .caption p {
    font-size: 1.2em;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-height: 400px) {
  .slide-container .slider .slide .caption {
    padding-top: 2px;
  }
  .slide-container .slider .slide .caption h2 {
  padding: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide .caption p {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1em;
}
  .hero-btn {
    position: relative;
    top:-40px;
  }
}
```

```html
<?php include ('header.php') ?>
<div class="hero-container">
    <span>Active Printing</span>
    <span style="margin-top: 150px; border: none; font-size: 20px; letter-spacing: 0em;"><a class="hero-btn" href="#services">Services</a></span>
</div>
<a href="#">
<div id="services" class="slide-container">
    <div class="slider">
        
        <div class="slide business1">
            <div class="caption">
                <h2>Business Printing</h2>
                <p>We service all your printing needs. Business cards, flyers, invoices and much more.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide business2">
            <div class="caption">
                <h2>Slide2</h2>
                <p>Test</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide business3">
            <div class="caption">
                <h2>Slide3</h2>
                <p>Test</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide business4">
            <div class="caption">
                <h2>Slide4</h2>
                <p>Test</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</a>

<div style="width: 100%; height: 5rem;">
</div>
<!-- <a href="#"><button class="slide-btn"><i class="fas fa-sort-up" style="margin-right: 5px;"></i>Business Printing<i style="margin-left: 5px;" class="fas fa-sort-up"></i></button></a> -->

<a href="#">
<div id="services" class="slide-container">
    <div class="slider">
        <div class="slide canvas1">
            <div class="caption">
                <h2>Canvas Printing</h2>
                <p>Canvas prints are a unique way to personalize any space and make great gifts.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide canvas2">
            <div class="caption">
                <h2>Slide2</h2>
                <p>Test</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide canvas3">
            <div class="caption">
                <h2>Slide3</h2>
                <p>Test</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide canvas4">
            <div class="caption">
                <h2>Slide4</h2>
                <p>Test</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</a>

<div style="width: 100%; height: 5rem;">
</div>
<!-- <a href="#"><button class="slide-btn"><i class="fas fa-sort-up" style="margin-right: 5px;"></i>Canvas Printing<i style="margin-left: 5px;" class="fas fa-sort-up"></i></button></a> -->

<a href="#">
<div id="services" class="slide-container">
    <div class="slider">
        <div class="slide embroidery1">
            <div class="caption">
                <h2>Embroidery</h2>
                <p>Embroidery is the craft of decorating fabric or other materials using a needle to apply thread or yarn. Embroidery may also incorporate other materials such as pearls, beads, quills, and sequins.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide embroidery2">
            <div class="caption">
                <h2>Slide2</h2>
                <p>Test</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide embroidery3">
            <div class="caption">
                <h2>Slide3</h2>
                <p>Test</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide embroidery4">
            <div class="caption">
                <h2>Slide4</h2>
                <p>Test</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</a>

<div style="width: 100%; height: 5rem;">
</div>
<!-- <a href="#"><button class="slide-btn"><i class="fas fa-sort-up" style="margin-right: 5px;"></i>Embroidery<i style="margin-left: 5px;" class="fas fa-sort-up"></i></button></a> -->


<?php include('footer.php') ?>
```

Comment: It seems like that did the trick, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

maybe this?....

i removed the following as shown by commented out.

```
.slide-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    /* height: 25vh; */
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 5px solid #1E90FF;
    box-shadow: 0 16px 32px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 10px 30px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}


.slide-container .slider {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    /* position: absolute; */
    /* top: 0; */
    /* left: 0; */
    width: 500%;
    height: 100%;
    /* float: left; */
    animation: animate 30s linear infinite;
}

    
.slide-container .slider .slide {
    position: relative;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    float : left;
}
   
.slide-container .slider .slide .caption {
    /* position: absolute; */
    /* bottom: 60px; */
    /* left: 60px; */
    /* right: 60px; */
    /* padding: 30px; */
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

and added

```
.slide-container .slider
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
```

Edit*
I noticed the button interferes on some mobile. you could.. 
add 
display: block; 
change the height from 15 to maybe 50px 
adjust your margin-top on the span

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

html {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 999;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 117rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 1.5rem;
}

.menu-icons{
    color: #eee;
    font-size: 4rem;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 2rem;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 1500;
    display: none;
}

nav {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 8rem;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(225,225,225, 0.1);
}

.logo {
    display: flex;
    margin-right: 5rem;
}

.nav-list {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
}

.nav-list li {
    line-height: 8rem;
    position: relative;
}

.sub-menu li {
    line-height: 4rem;
}

.nav-list a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    background-color: #1E90FF;
    padding: 0 1.5rem;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transition: color 650ms;
    transition: background-color 650ms;
}

.nav-list a:hover {
    color: black;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.cart {
    height: 30px;
    width: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.btn {
    padding: 1.3rem;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #1E90FF;
    border: 2px solid #1E90FF;
    border-radius: 5rem;
    transition: background-color 650ms;
}

.btn:hover {
    color: black;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.sub-menu {
    width: 20rem;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    border-top: 3px solid #00BFFF;
    z-index: 100;
    top: 16rem;
    transition: all 650ms ease;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.sub-menu::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -2.5rem;
    left: 3rem;
    border: 1.2rem solid transparent;
    border-bottom-color: #00BFFF;
}

.sub-menu .sub-menu::before {
    top: .9rem;
    left: -2.5rem;
    border: 1.2rem solid transparent;
    border-right-color: #00BFFF;
}

.sub-menu .sub-menu{
    border-top: none;
    border-left: 3px solid #00BFFF;
    top: 0;
    left: 160%;
}

.nav-list li:hover > .sub-menu {
    top: 8rem;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}

.sub-menu li:hover > .sub-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
}
    
li.move-right {
    margin: auto 0 auto auto;
    line-height: initial;
    transition: color 650ms;
    transition: background-color 650ms;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1050px) {
    .nav-list {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        height: 100vh;
        display:none;
        align-items: initial;
        flex-direction: column;
        background-color: #1E90FF;
        z-index: 1000;
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }
    
    .nav-list li {
        line-height: 6rem;
    }
    
    .sub-menu {
        position: initial;
        border: 3px solid transparent;
        border-left-color: #00BFFF;
        margin-left: 1rem;
        max-height: 0;
    }
    
    .sub-menu::before {
        display: none;
    }
    
    .nav-list li:hover > .sub-menu{
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
        max-height: initial;
    }
    
    li.move-right {
        margin: 0 auto 0 0;
        line-height: initial;
    }
    
    .menu-icons {
        display: block;
    }
    
    .fas fa-times {
        display: none;
    }
    
    nav.active .fas fa-times{
        display: block;
    }
    
    nav.active .fas fa-bars{
        display: none;
    }
    
    nav.active .nav-list {
        display:flex;
    }
}

.hero-container {
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: linear-gradient(
    rgba(0,0,0,0.5),
    rgba(0,0,0,0.5)),
    url(../images/heroImage.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    
}

.hero-container span {
    color: white;
    font-size: 50px;
    letter-spacing: 0.2em;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border: 10px solid white;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 3px 14px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.hero-container a {
    padding: 15px 16px;
    color: white;
    background-color: #1E90FF;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 5rem;
    transition: background-color 650ms;
}

.hero-btn:hover {
    color: black;
    background-color: yellow;
    transition: background-color 650ms;
}

.slide-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    /* height: 25vh; */
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 5px solid #1E90FF;
    box-shadow: 0 16px 32px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 10px 30px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}


.slide-container .slider {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    /* position: absolute; */
    /* top: 0; */
    /* left: 0; */
    width: 500%;
    height: 100%;
    /* float: left; */
    animation: animate 30s linear infinite;
}

    
.slide-container .slider .slide {
    position: relative;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    float : left;
}
    
.slide-container .slider .slide .caption {
    /* position: absolute; */
    /* bottom: 60px; */
    /* left: 60px; */
    /* right: 60px; */
    /* padding: 30px; */
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide .caption h2 {
    margin: 0 0 20px;
    padding: 0;
    color: white;
    font-size: 48px;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide .caption p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
}



.slide-container .slider .slide.business1 {
    background: url(../images/business1.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.business2 {
    background: url(../images/business2.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.business3 {
    background: url(../images/business3.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.business4 {
    background: url(../images/business4.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.canvas1 {
    background: url(../images/canvas1.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.canvas2 {
    background: url(../images/canvas2.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.canvas3 {
    background: url(../images/canvas3.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.canvas4 {
    background: url(../images/canvas4.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.embroidery1 {
    background: url(../images/embroidery1.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.embroidery2 {
    background: url(../images/embroidery2.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.embroidery3 {
    background: url(../images/embroidery3.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.embroidery4 {
    background: url(../images/embroidery4.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}



@keyframes animate {
    0% 
    {
        left: 0;
    }
    
    20% 
    {
        left: 0;
    }
    
    25% 
    {
        left: -100%;
    }
    
    45% 
    {
        left: -100%;
    }
    50% 
    {
        left: -200%;
    }
    70% 
    {
        left: -200%;
    }
    75% 
    {
        left: -300%;
    }
    95% 
    {
        left: -300%;
    }
    100% {
        left: -400%;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .slide-container .slider .slide .caption{
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide .caption h2 {
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide .caption p {
    font-size: 16px;
}

}

.slide-btn {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 5rem;
    border: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    background-color: white;
    transition: background-color 650ms;
}

.slide-btn:hover {
    background-color: #1E90FF;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: background-color 650ms;
}

.footer-row {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.footer {
    background-color: #1E90FF;
    padding: 70px 0;
    
}

.footer-container {
    max-width: 1170px;
    margin: auto;
}

li {
    list-style: none;
}

.footer-col {
    width: 25%;
    padding: 0 15px;
}

.footer-col h4 {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: white;
    text-transform: capatalize;
    margin-bottom: 35px;
    font-weight: 500;
    position: relative;
}

.footer-col h4::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -10px;
    background-color: white;
    height: 2px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 50px;
}

.footer-col ul li:not(:last-child) {
    margin-bottom: 10px;

}

.footer-col ul li a {
    font-size: 16px;
    text-transform: capatalize;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.footer-col ul li a:hover {
    color: yellow;
    padding-left: 8px;
}

.footer-col .social-links {
    display: inline-block;
     /* height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);*/
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: white;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.footer-col .social-links:hover {
    color: yellow;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .footer-col 
    {
        width: 50%;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
    }
    
}

@media (max-width: 574px) {
    .footer-col 
    {
        width: 100%;
    }
    
}
```

```html
<div class="hero-container">
    <span>Active Printing</span>
    <span style="margin-top: 150px; border: none; font-size: 20px; letter-spacing: 0em;"><a class="hero-btn" href="#services">Services</a></span>
</div>
<a href="#">
<div id="services" class="slide-container">
    <div class="slider">
        
        <div class="slide business1">
            <div class="caption">
                <h2>Business Printing</h2>
                <p>We service all your printing needs. Business cards, flyers, invoices and much more.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide business2">
            <div class="caption">
                <h2>Slide2</h2>
                <p>Test</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide business3">
            <div class="caption">
                <h2>Slide3</h2>
                <p>Test</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide business4">
            <div class="caption">
                <h2>Slide4</h2>
                <p>Test</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</a>

<div style="width: 100%; height: 5rem;">
</div>
<!-- <a href="#"><button class="slide-btn"><i class="fas fa-sort-up" style="margin-right: 5px;"></i>Business Printing<i style="margin-left: 5px;" class="fas fa-sort-up"></i></button></a> -->

<a href="#">
<div id="services" class="slide-container">
    <div class="slider">
        <div class="slide canvas1">
            <div class="caption">
                <h2>Canvas Printing</h2>
                <p>Canvas prints are a unique way to personalize any space and make great gifts.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide canvas2">
            <div class="caption">
                <h2>Slide2</h2>
                <p>Test</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide canvas3">
            <div class="caption">
                <h2>Slide3</h2>
                <p>Test</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide canvas4">
            <div class="caption">
                <h2>Slide4</h2>
                <p>Test</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</a>

<div style="width: 100%; height: 5rem;">
</div>
<!-- <a href="#"><button class="slide-btn"><i class="fas fa-sort-up" style="margin-right: 5px;"></i>Canvas Printing<i style="margin-left: 5px;" class="fas fa-sort-up"></i></button></a> -->

<a href="#">
<div id="services" class="slide-container">
    <div class="slider">
        <div class="slide embroidery1">
            <div class="caption">
                <h2>Embroidery</h2>
                <p>Embroidery is the craft of decorating fabric or other materials using a needle to apply thread or yarn. Embroidery may also incorporate other materials such as pearls, beads, quills, and sequins.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide embroidery2">
            <div class="caption">
                <h2>Slide2</h2>
                <p>Test</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide embroidery3">
            <div class="caption">
                <h2>Slide3</h2>
                <p>Test</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide embroidery4">
            <div class="caption">
                <h2>Slide4</h2>
                <p>Test</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</a>

<div style="width: 100%; height: 5rem;">
</div>
```